# check if a file in a plugin folder exists from a locale installation

Tags: plugins, local-installation, plugins-url, function-exists

I need to check if a file exist in my plugin dir:

```
if (fileexists) {
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

However, if in place of fileexists I use `file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR  . "/myplugin/myfile.ext")` it returns always true, whereas if I use `file_exists(plugins_url( "myfile.ext", __FILE__ ))` it returns always false, irrespective of the argument I use is a file that exists or not.

I do not know if it is relevant to specify that I'm working in a locale environment. WP_PLUGIN_DIR returns `C:\Users\MyName\Documents\webserver\www\wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myfile.ext` (and I see some slashes and some backslashes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
if( file_exists(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'myfile.ext') ) {}
```

instead of

```
if( file_exists( plugins_url( "myfile.ext", __FILE__ ) ) ) {}
```

See [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) in the Codex.